# Angular2 @Input : Passing an objects array from parent to child component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I need some help with angular 2. Is it possible to pass an objects array from parent to child component? It seems its not possible, But maybe i missed something. Below you could see a summary what ive been trying in my code.

```
parent.component.ts
-----------------------------------------

@Component({
    template: `
        <child dataset="{{ people }}"></child>  
    `,
})

export class ParentComponent{

    private people: any[] = [
        { name: 'jimmy', age: 22, gender: 'male' },
        { name: 'johnny', age: 23, gender: 'male' },
        { name: 'danny', age: 24, gender: 'male' }
    ];

}


child.component.ts
-----------------------------------------
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit{

@Input() private dataset: any[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.dataset);
    }  

}


console
-----------------------------------------
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Comment: It seems to work, no? What is actually the problem?

Comment: Interpolation converts expression to string. Use property binding like `[dataset]="people"`

Comment: Thanks: [dataset]="people" works!

Comment: @yurzui 
Hi, That sounds cool.
would be great if you can answer the question in the answer section so that question will appear as answered with a solution.

Answer (score 5):

The interpolation like `dataset="{{ people }}">` is always stringified while the value of basic property binding `[dataset]="people"` is passed as is.

So you need to replace interpolation with:

```
[dataset]="people"
```

See also

- [What's the difference between `value="{{todo.title}}"` and `[value]="todo.title"`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925916/whats-the-difference-between-value-todo-title-and-value-todo-title)
- https://vsavkin.com/angular-2-template-syntax-5f2ee9f13c6a#.6umy3rw04