# Difference between 2 type of displaying data in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have some Angular2 code:

```
<img [src]="value">
```

and

```
<img src="{{value}}">
```

> Note: ***value*** is a property component

I tested myself and the result is the same, so what is the difference between them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** **NOTE** : don't use `""` & `{{}}` together else value will be stringified.

```
src="{{value}}"
```

**`value`** will always be **stringified**.

---

**2)**

Here, **`value`** is an **`expression`** which will be evaluated for the **`property binding`**.

**`[src]`** to be precise, this is an angular2 way **`property binding`** syntax.

```
 <img [src]="value">
```

So, it will bind **`value's`** evaluated value to **`src property`**.

Answer (score 2):

They are both **properties bindings**

Interpolation

```
<img src="{{value}}">
```

is just sugar for

```
<img [src]="interpolate(value)">
```

So the difference between those expressions is that the value in the **interpolation** `src="{{value}}"` is **always stringified** while the value of basic property binding `[src]="value"` is passed as is.

See also

- [What's the difference between `value="{{todo.title}}"` and `[value]="todo.title"`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925916/whats-the-difference-between-value-todo-title-and-value-todo-title/39928705#39928705)
- [Angular 2 Template Syntax](https://vsavkin.com/angular-2-template-syntax-5f2ee9f13c6a#.z50qcnblo)