# What is the difference [value] = "mystring" and value = {{mystring}}

Tags: angular, angular5

When you do binding in angular what is the difference between [value] = "mystring" and value = {{mystring}}?
is there any problem if I will bind by second variant? Or the second do not bind at all? Sorry for this silly question, I am just new at angular5

Comment: [Probably related](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). You only tag angular and not JS, so I'm not sure...

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't related to destructuring (@user202729) just talking about the syntax for property binding in angular 2+
As far as I know there isn't a major difference but I'm mostly versed with 1.x
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/108/Angular-5-Interpolation,-Property-Binding-&-Event-Binding-Tutorial  As @user202729 mentioned though on SO you  should only tag with "angular".  The "angularjs" tag is for 1.x

Comment: ok, I see, thanx for reply

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200802/difference-between-2-type-of-displaying-data-in-angular-2/40200828#40200828

Answer (score 0):

Both do the same, the first is called interpolation and the second is named property bindings.
When you use interpolation, Angular converts it to property bindings. 
I recommend you to use the one with you feel more readable!!